# Connecting Two Anchors Horizontally from Different Shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I have defined two shapes: `myComponent1`, which includes two anchors (`PinA` and `PinB`), and `myComponent2`, which includes one anchor (`PinA`). I am seeking guidance on how to directly connect `PinA` from `myComponent1` to `PinA` from `myComponent2` using a horizontal wire. Below, you will find my LaTeX code along with the corresponding output. Lastly, I have included the desired outcome.

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

%% defining My Component 1
\pgfdeclareshape{myComponent1}{
    
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    
    \savedanchor\PinA{\pgfpoint{60}{50}}
    \anchor{PinA}{\PinA}
    \savedanchor\PinB{\pgfpoint{60}{-50}}
    \anchor{PinB}{\PinB}
    
    \foregroundpath{
        
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-60}{-100}}{\pgfpoint{60}{100}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        
        \pgftext[right, at={\PinA}]{PIN A}
        \pgftext[right, at={\PinB}]{PIN B}
    }
}

%% defining My Component 2
\pgfdeclareshape{myComponent2}{
    
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    
    \savedanchor\PinA{\pgfpoint{-60}{0}}
    \anchor{PinA}{\PinA}
    
    \foregroundpath{
        
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-60}{-100}}{\pgfpoint{60}{100}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        
        \pgftext[left, at={\PinA}]{PIN A}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{circuitikz}

        \draw (0,0) node[myComponent1, blue] (C1) {};
        \draw (8,5) node[myComponent2, red]  (C2) {};
        
        \draw (C1.PinA) -- (C2.PinA);
    
    \end{circuitikz}
    
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**DESIRED OUTCOME:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the two shapes have the anchors at different vertical positions, you can't (obviously) connect them with an horizontal line.

What you can do is draw the first shape, draw an horizontal line, and then add the second shape using the anchor:

```
 \draw (0,0) node[myComponent1, blue] (C1) {};
 \draw (C1.PinA) -- ++(3,0) node[myComponent2, red, anchor=PinA] (C2) {};
```

[image]

Anyway, that has nothing specific to `circuitikz`, it's plain Ti*k*Z... omplete MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% defining My Component 1
\pgfdeclareshape{myComponent1}{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \savedanchor\PinA{\pgfpoint{60}{50}}
    \anchor{PinA}{\PinA}
    \savedanchor\PinB{\pgfpoint{60}{-50}}
    \anchor{PinB}{\PinB}
    \foregroundpath{
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-60}{-100}}{\pgfpoint{60}{100}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        \pgftext[right, at={\PinA}]{PIN A}
        \pgftext[right, at={\PinB}]{PIN B}
    }
}
%% defining My Component 2
\pgfdeclareshape{myComponent2}{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \savedanchor\PinA{\pgfpoint{-60}{0}}
    \anchor{PinA}{\PinA}
    \foregroundpath{
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-60}{-100}}{\pgfpoint{60}{100}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        \pgftext[left, at={\PinA}]{PIN A}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[myComponent1, blue] (C1) {};
    \draw (C1.PinA) -- ++(3,0) node[myComponent2, red, anchor=PinA] (C2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```